# Process words in a scanner to string array

Tags: java, arrays, junit, java.util.scanner

I am fairly new to programming and am trying to devise a way to create a method with multiple parameters. A scanner, a string array of words, a string array matching the word array with how many times the word is used, and an integer with how many words are in the string array. My goal is to process the words in the scanner one by one, if a word in the scanner is also in the word array I want to add one to the int array, if a word is not the word array I want to add it to the word array at the first null space on the array and add one to the int array at the same location as the word. The goal of the method is to return how many words are in the word array after processing the words in the scanner. My first attempt pulls a nullPointerException on the .equals(). 
My Method

```
public static int scanScanner(Scanner s,String[] words, int[] wordCount, int wordsInWordsArray) {
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String currentToken = s.next();
        if(words[i].equals(currentToken)) {
            wordScore[i]=+lineScore;
            wordCount[i]++;
        }
        else {
            words[wordsInWordsArray] = currentToken;
            wordScore[wordsInWordsArray]=+lineScore;
            wordCount[wordsInWordsArray]++;
            wordsInWordsArray++;
        }
    }
    return wordsInWordsArray;
    }
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. When your code throws an npe, then there is bug there that needs fixing. Beyond that: why are putting so many different aspects into one single method? Start slow! Solve one task, test it extensively. Then the next one. And then, when all parts work, see how you might want to combine them. Also note that "combining" two pieces of information using "the same index" in two different arrays is counter intuitive in good OOP. consider using lists instead of arrays, they allow you to simply append elements, instead of looking for empty slots.

Comment: Finally: don't do 5 tests in one test. Write small tests, that focus on one aspect, and rather have many of these smaller tests.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1. Your outer loop should be iterating over the words in the scanner, not the words in your array. As you have it now, if you happened to start with an empty array, your method would do nothing.
2. Is there a reason you need arrays? In general you should prefer the `java.util` collection classes over arrays. They will handle the resizing for you. In this case, a `Map<String, Stats>` seems like the way to go, where `Stats` would be a class you create that contains both the count and score. And if the score is a function of just the count, then all you need is the count and could use `Map<String, Integer>`.

Your approach here seems unnecessarily complicated.